# R: How can I modify my dataset for survival analysis?

Tags: r, dataset, survival-analysis

I'm trying to perform survival analysis using `R`. I have the dataset that looks like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Tdi.png).

I want to analyze the difference of survival between two types. `S6`, `S12`, `S18`... is the follow-up month which shows whether patient survived or died.(6 months, 12 months, 18 months and so on...)

As the actual dataset contains large number of patients, it is impossible to calculate survival time manually.

I wish for your support.

Comment: Hi Choi, welcome to SO. Please add code snippet of what have you tried ?

Comment: I couldn't get a clue for this.. I googled but most of the pages were based on dataset with calculated follow-up duration.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following works for you. Let me know if there's an issue - I've added a comment at every step so you can understand what I did. There are more elegant solutions using tidyverse for the data manipulations but I did this quickly as I have limited time right now. If possible, please supply the dataset in future to make it a bit easier to figure out the specific problems.

```
# Import the dataset here - I'm generating mine from scratch but import yours using read.csv or similar

df <- data.frame(pt = 1:6, type = rep(0:1, 3), s0 = c("S", "S", "S", "", "S", "S"), 
              s6 = c("S", "", "S", "", "S", "S"), s12 = c("S", "", "D", "", "D", ""))

# Data manipulation starts here
library(tidyr)
# Replace s12 below with the largest followup event you have
long_df <- tidyr::gather(df, followupRaw, status, s0:s12) # Converts to long form which I prefer to work with - ignore warning message if related to attributes not identical
long_df$status <- factor(long_df$status, levels = c("S", "D")) # Converts to factor and coerces blank to NA values (important)
long_df$followup <- as.numeric(substring(long_df$followupRaw, 2)) # Removes the s character to convert each followup to an integer - make sure all followup periods are in the sXX format

# Form final dataframe for survival analysis
survivalDf <- data.frame(patient = unique(df$pt)) # Single row per patient
survivalDf$followupAvailable <- sapply(survivalDf$patient, function(x) (sum(!is.na(long_df[long_df$pt == x, "status"]))) > 0) # Logical vector so that we can idenify what rows have a followup event recorded (T) versus missing (F)
survivalDf <- survivalDf[survivalDf$followupAvailable,] # Remove patients with no followup
survivalDf$type <- sapply(survivalDf$patient, function(x) df[df$pt == x, "type"]) # Add type to final dataframe
survivalDf$lastFollowup <- sapply(survivalDf$patient, function(x) max(long_df[long_df$pt == x & !is.na(long_df$status), "followup"])) # Find last instance of followup
survivalDf$status <- mapply(function(x, y) long_df[long_df$pt == x & long_df$followup == y, "status"], survivalDf$patient, survivalDf$lastFollowup) # Add patient status at last followup
survivalDf$statusKM <- ifelse(survivalDf$status == "S", 0, ifelse(survivalDf$status == "D", 1, survivalDf$status)) # Convert to Kaplan Meier friendly format: 0-censored, 1-death

# Survival analysis here
library(survival)
library(survminer)
km <- survfit(Surv(lastFollowup, statusKM) ~ type, data = survivalDf)
summary(km) # Table of data
ggsurvplot(km, data = survivalDf) # Kaplan Meier of result
```

Comment: You deserve more than my paltry upvote but that's all I can do. There's no way to drag questioners back and threaten them until they do the right thing an mark the question as answered.